# Unable to insert data to MySQL with Python/MySQL Connector

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to Python (learnt how to code with it in 2 days ago). I'm trying to get feeds from MySQL database and insert theme into other table. But nothing inserted.

Here is my code:

```
    cnx = MySQLConnection(**db_config)
    if cnx.is_connected():
        print("Database connected successfully...")

    cursor = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from external_feeds WHERE discipline = 'ALL' AND actif = 1")

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    insert_feed = ("INSERT INTO feeds "
    "(categorie, urlflux, titreflux, photonews, textnews, date, titrenews, liensnews, slug, photo)"
    "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")


    for row in rows:
        feed = feedparser.parse(row["url"])
        feed_link = row["url"]
        name = row["name"]
        image = row["photo"]
        category = row["discipline"]

        x = len(feed.entries)
        for i in range(x):
            feed_title = feed.entries[i].title
            print feed_title
            feed_url = feed.entries[i].link
            print feed_url
            feed_published = feed.entries[i].published
            dPubPretty = strftime(feed_published, gmtime())
            feed_description = feed.entries[i].description
            slug = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\-]', '', feed_url)
            slug = slug.replace('httpwww', '')
            slug = slug.replace('http', '')
            # print insert_feed
            data_feed = (category, feed_link, name, None, feed_description, dPubPretty, feed_title, feed_url, slug, image)
            try:
                cursor.execute(insert_feed, data_feed)
                cursor.commit()
            except:
                cnx.rollback()
                cursor.close()
```

Is there anyone who can help me figure out where the problem is? I am completly new to this so I'm totally lost

Comment: You should add a `raise` to the end of your `except` block for debugging, just to see the error traceback. At the moment the error is masked by your `try`/`except`.

Comment: Thank you alot, I added raise in the end of except block but nothing happens.

Comment: Why don't you use insert ... select ... statement to handle insertion of records from one table to the other?

Comment: @Shadow: I'm just new to programming :D 
I just find out I have to commit connection _cnx.commit()_ not cursor.

Comment: That may fix the above code, however, the above code will still be slow and waste of resources compared to an insert ... select ... that was designed to do what you are doing, without the need of fetching each row to be copied to your application first.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are performing 'cursor.commit()' after inserting the data, which is incorrect, try using 'cnx.commit()'.